# handle click on Ext.js panel header

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am trying to handle clicks on ext.js panel header (living inside of an accordion with other panels..), now the header is an extended header, and it contains a number of items (not tools) in it. Problem is that when I set titleCollapse:true, clicks on my items are propagated to the header, which collapses.

I want to set titleCollapse:true so I the users will be able to collapse/expand by clicking the header and not only the collapse tool. But, then, this problem..

Answer (score 2):

let me answer myself...

```
Ext.define("WebPhone.view.CallLogListHeader", {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Header',
    xtype: 'callLogListHeader',
    layout:
    {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'middle',
        pack: 'end'
    },
    //titlePosition: 0,
    items:
    [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: '',
            cls: 'ClearCallLogButtonCls',
            handler: function () {
                var me = this;
                me.container.component.handledByTool = true;
                var view = Ext.create('WebPhone.view.ApproveClearLogs');
                view.show();
            }
        }
    ],
    initComponent: function()
    {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent( arguments );
        me.handledByTool = false;
    },
    listeners:
    {
        click: function()
        {
            var me = this;
            if( me.handledByTool )
            {
                me.handledByTool = false;
                return;
            }

            var parent = me.findParentByType( 'contact-list-view' );
            if( parent.collapsed )
                parent.expand();
            else
                parent.collapse();
        }
    }
});
```